# onOptionsItemSelected not called

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

I have a list of menu items in my actionbar. Each item click should trigger a different method. But onOptionsItemSelected is never called.

This is how the actionbar is defined in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings_1) {
            //do something
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.action_settings_2) {
            //do something
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.action_settings_1) {
            //do something
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
...
}
```

This is the actionbar menu layout menu_main:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings_1"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="Item 1"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings_2"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="Item 2"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings_3"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="Item 3"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

How can I set up the actionbar so that onOptionsItemSelected is called when an actionbar item is clicked?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Inside your `onCreateOptionsMenu`, return true instead of calling super. That should do it

Comment: There is no return type of boolean in this override method

Comment: This in on the Activity. The return type is void on the Fragment

Comment: How about for `ListActivity` i tried it does not work

Answer (score 3):

In the onCreate(), call setSupportActionbar(), like so

```
toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Instead of implement

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu
...
```

In activity_main.xml add:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
        app:title="@string/myTitle"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main"
        >
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Next, in menu_main.xml add in each item:

```
android:onClick="onOptionsItemSelected"
```

Like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings_1"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="Item 1"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:onClick="onOptionsItemSelected" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings_2"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="Item 2"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:onClick="onOptionsItemSelected" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings_3"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="Item 3"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:onClick="onOptionsItemSelected" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was not adding `android:onClick="onOptionsItemSelected"
` for my each items.
I still don't understand the reason to explicitly define it. Would be great if you can tell the reason or any blog post which can do the same.
Anyways thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just do the change as below :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Cannot find `R.menu` nor `menu_main` where is it

Answer (score 1):

This problem can potentially also happen if using the `menu` attribute in XML:

```
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            app:menu="@menu/your_menu"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/..."
            app:title="@string/..." />
```

So `app:menu="@menu/your_menu"` doesn't work with the overridden fragment method `onOptionsItemSelected`. The menu item click listener has to be set to the `Toolbar`

```
private fun setMenuClickListener(toolbar: MaterialToolbar) = with(toolbar) {
        setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem ->
            if (menuItem.itemId == R.id.yourId) {
                //do something
                return@setOnMenuItemClickListener true
            }
             //this is a lambda so it can be just false,
             //added return to make it explicit
            return@setOnMenuItemClickListener false
        }
    }
```

So what we are looking for is the `setOnMenuItemClickListener` from `MaterialToolbar`